# Laravel form-data image and text fields validation

Tags: laravel, rest, api, upload, postman

```
//TestRequest.php
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'name' => 'string|required|min:5',
        'tip' => 'string|required|min:5',
        'answer' => 'string|required',
        'image' => 'file|required|mimes:png,jpg,jpeg'
    ];
}


//TestController.php
public function put(TestRequest $request)
{
    $validated = $request->validated();
}
```

[image]

[image]

I'm doing some rest API. I need a form with some text fields and one image upload field but I have a problem with validating it.

1. When I'm sending the request as 'form-data' in the Postman, Laravel doesn't see in the validation any fields (why?).
2. When I'm sending the request as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` Laravel sees my text fields, but I can't, of course, upload the image.

API will be used by the android APP. How I can solve this? How I can have both validation on text and file inputs?

Answer (score 0):

Using `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` is the correct way to upload images. According to your second screenshot, you are not sending the file field in Postman, but you are sending it in the first screenshot.

Comment: Because it's not possible to add image with urlencoded. Or I don't know how.

Answer (score 0):

see this

```
'name' => 'string|required|min:5',
```

minimum is 5 character but you send `test` or 4 chars. Laravel validation rule, if it failed it will stop or next validation will not checked.

Comment: No, if string is longer, I get the same result.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've found a solution.
Changing method from PUT to POST seems to fix this issue.